# Telerik.web.ui Is Missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I am Telerik controls in my project, Error is telerik.web.ui is not found, Coudn't find assembly

I have added `Telerik.web.ui.dll` inside Bin directory

Reference Code is available inside web.config

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a 64 bit comp then you will need to add the 64 bit version of `Telerik.web.ui.dll` that is properly the problem

Answer (score 0):

Download Telerik DLLs and install them using NuGet Package installer . This will solve your problem and you may need not to worry about manually adding each and every DLL which are needed for your project

Comment: Which nuget package contains the Telerik.Web.UI namespace components?